# Why does git tag local create two tags on remote after push?

Tags: git, git-tag, git-workflow

I am creating a git branch B off branch A.

```
$git checkout A
$git checkout -b B
```

I change some files in branch B, then

```
$git add <files>
$git commit -m "a message"
```

Then I create a tag while branch B is active

```
$git tag -a <tag_name>
```

I am still on local.

I then checkout branch A

```
$git checkout A
```

merge branch B into A

```
$git merge B
```

I push branch A

```
$git push origin A
```

then I push tags, while I am still in branch A

```
$git push origin tag <tag_name>
```

now if I list tags on remote, I see two tags by doing:

```
$git ls-remote --tags

<tag_name>
<tag_name>^{}
```

with `^{}` appended to a second entry

Can someone explain what the reasons are here?

Why do I see two tags on remote?

On local, there is just one

```
$git tag -l
<tag_name>
```

---

Is the order I am doing this common? Or a different order suggested?  I really just want a tag on Branch B (and all the files there).

Answer (score 5):

> now if I list tags on remote, I see two tags by doing:
>
> ```
> $git ls-remote --tags
>
> <tag_name>
> <tag_name>^{}
> ```

You're not seeing two tags.  That's just how `git ls-remote` displays *one* tag, provided that this one tag is an *annotated tag*.  The first output line shows you the tag itself, and the hash ID of the underlying annotated tag object.  The second output line shows you the tag with `^{}` appended, and the hash ID of the *target object* (the commit you tagged).

The reason you see both of these is that the Git protocols expose both hash IDs for `git fetch` to work efficiently.  The `git ls-remote` command just uses what is already there for `git fetch`, and hence shows this as well.

If you create a *lightweight tag*, the output from `git ls-remote` will have only one line, but lightweight tags are generally discouraged for distribution, as they can't carry any additional information such as a PGP signature.

Comment: OK, thank you.  I will need to parse through the answer and research more to understand completely, but have the material I need to go on.  I just wanted to make sure that everything was in order, that I was not seeing something as a result of tagging or pushing incorrectly.